# Rails is not passing the "commit" button parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Reinstalling a Rails app on a new server.  Part of the app can fork in one of two directions based on the button the user selects.  This part isn't working, and when I look at the log I see the values that I gave the form, **execept** for the `commit` portion of the params hash.  This seems to be why the app isn't working as expected (since there's nothing in `params[:commit]`, but I have no idea why commit would not be passed in; the request is definitely a POST request, and all of the other parameters are there.

Comment: Have you found a solution yet? I'm having a similar problem since I updated my template with one from my web designer. Use a 'basic' template and all is file, but use the designers (HTML valid) template and I don't get commit values.

Comment: In my case it was due to having a jQuery popup prior to actually submitting the form.

Comment: Thanks for that comment Wayne, that tipped me off to what caused this for me.  In my case, we had a generic jQuery submit event binding that was disabling the submit button (to avoid double submits).  Removing that from this form fixed things.

Comment: I had something similar: if you use submit_tag's disable_with feature, it does not pass the "commit" param.

Comment: cheers @chrisbailey, i was listening for a click on the submit buttons, disabling various things and showing loading throbbers then doing a jQuery `.submit()` . I had to keep that code, so instead of listening for the `click` on the buttons, I now listen for the `submit` on the form `$("#my-form").submit(function(e){....code goes here...})` and I do not have to do a manual `.submit()` (NOTE I was doing manual submit because chrome prevented default behaviour when listening for click on submit button FF does not prevent it.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Had a simular problem with a disable-button-on-submit feature. We solved it by adding a hidden input field with the same name and value before submitting the form.

```
function disableButtonAndSubmit()
{
  var input = $("<input type='hidden' />").attr("name", $(this)[0].name).attr("value", $(this)[0].value);
  $(this).closest('form').append(input);
  $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled').html('Loading…');
  $(this).closest('form').submit();
}

$('#somewhere button').click(disableButtonAndSubmit);
```

Answer (score 8):

Just add `name: "commit", value: "Save"`to your form submit button:

```
form_for @object do |f|
  ...
  f.button :submit, "Save", name: "commit", value:"Save"
end
```

and then you will have `params[:commit]` equals to `"Save"` in the controller.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this same problem, and the answers here pointed me in the right direction. However, rather than the suggestions to be adding hidden form inputs or giving up on the double submit block, you can simply add a setTimeout function on your double submit block with a timeout of 1 millisecond, which allows the double submit block to work without preventing the submission of the button.

Answer (score 1):

Check that your submit input is named commit or it's label will not be sent.

The resulting html should be:

```
<input type="submit" name="commit" label="...>
```

Answer (score 0):

I looked into something like this awhile ago, where there is inconsistency in how different browsers would pass in the value of a submit button on a form.  I found the only practical solution was to have javascript in the button to set a hidden field, and use that value instead.

Here is some of my code to differentiate between a save and exit, which goes one way, and save and continue which go another:

```
  <%= hidden_field_tag 'step_commit', '' %>
  <span style="float:left;">
    <%=submit_tag 'Cancel', :name=>'cancel', :onclick=>"javascript:location.href='/';return false;" %>
    <%=submit_tag 'Save and Exit', :name=>'exit', :onclick=>"javascript:$('step_commit').value='exit';" %>
  </span>
  <span style="float:right;">
    <%=submit_tag 'Save and Continue', :name=>'continue', :onclick=>"javascript:$('step_commit').value='continue';" %>
  </span>
```

Comment: The weird thing is it was working fine on the old server, but we just moved it over now and it stopped.